# Training haar Required leaf false alarm rate achieved. Branch training terminated

Tags: android, opencv, training-data

I have a problem with the training of haar cascade, i have 2000 positive image create with opencv_createsamples and 3032 negative image take in internet.
When i run the training with the command

> opencv_traincascade -data classifier/ -vec positive.vec -bg
>   Stop/negative.txt -numPos 700 -numNeg 2000 -numStages 20 -h 24 -w 24

At the stage 13 give me this error:

> POS count : consumed   700 : 728 NEG count : acceptanceRatio    2000 :
>   7.75856e-007 Required leaf false alarm rate achieved. Branch training terminated.

I don't understand why it give me this error!
Can someone help me please? Thanks.

Comment: http://answers.opencv.org/question/14165/required-leaf-false-alarm-rate-achieved-branch-training-terminated/

Comment: You think i need more positive? I try with 1000 image but it give me the same error, i modify -numPos 1000 and the same negative.